# Compile error: "undefined reference to AList<Pwm>::AList()" Arduino C++

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm using the [AList library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/668818/Implementing-a-Doubly-Linked-List) to create a doubly linked list for Arduino, but I get compile errors while defining it. The library was not written by me, and other people have used it successfully, so I assume it's not the problem, but my code is the problem. I'm also using the Arduino IDE, so I assume it's not a linker error. Here is my main file (main.ino):

```
 #include "project.h"
 //other stuff
```

project.h:

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "AList.h"
#include "PWM.h"
//other stuff
```

PWM.h:

```
#ifndef PWM_H
#define PWM_H

class Pwm{
  public:
  static AList<Pwm> pwms;
  static int numPwms;
  //other stuff
};

#endif
```

PWM.cpp:

```
#include "project.h"

int Pwm::numPwms = 0;
AList<Pwm> Pwm::pwms;
//other stuff
```

AList.h:

```
#ifndef ALIST_H
#define ALIST_H

template <typename ListItem>
class AList{

private:
    /** Intended for private representation of a ListItem within the AList class - Internal use only!
    @author Marco Bertschi
    */
    struct PrivateListItem{
        PrivateListItem* prv;
        PrivateListItem* nxt;
        ListItem crnt;
    };

    PrivateListItem* last;      //!< The last item of the list.
    PrivateListItem* first;     //!< The first item of the list.
    int count;                  //!< Zero-based count of items within the list.

public:
    AList();
    ~AList();
    ListItem First();
    ListItem Last();

    int Count();
    void Add(ListItem listItem);
    void RemAt(int index);
    ListItem GetAt(int index);
    void Clr();
};

#endif //ALIST_H
```

And finally, AList.cpp:

```
#include "AList.h"

//! Instantiates a new instance of an AList.
/*!
\return     AList<ListItem>     A new instance of an AList.
*/
template <typename ListItem>
AList<ListItem>::AList(){
    count = -1;
}
//! Destroys the instance of AList<ListItem>.
/*!
The AList<ListItem>::Clr() is called in order to free memory which
was previously occupied by the dynamically allocated list items.
\sa Clr();
*/
template <typename ListItem>
AList<ListItem>::~AList(){
    if (count > -1){
        Clr(); //Clear the List in order to free memory
    }
}
//! Adds an Item of the type ListItem to the AList.
/*!
\param      li      [ListItem]      The ListItem which is added to the AList.
\return     void    [void]      
*/
template <typename ListItem>
void AList<ListItem>::Add(ListItem li){
    PrivateListItem* pLItem = new PrivateListItem;
    pLItem->crnt = li;

    if (count > -1){
        pLItem->nxt = first;
        pLItem->prv = last;
        last->nxt = pLItem;
        last = pLItem;
        count++;
    }
    else if (count == -1){
        first = pLItem;
        first->nxt = pLItem;
        first->prv = pLItem;
        last = pLItem;
        last->nxt = pLItem;
        last->prv = pLItem;
        count = 0;
    }
}
//! Removes a ListItem from a given index position in the AList.
/*!
In case that there is no ListItem stored at the given index of the List 
no operation will be done and the list remains unchanged.

\param      index   [int]   The Index at which the ListItem gets removed.
\return     void    [void]
*/
template <typename ListItem>
void AList<ListItem>::RemAt(int index){
    if (index < count){
        PrivateListItem* pLItem = last;
        for (int i = 0; i <= index; i++){
            pLItem = pLItem->nxt;
        }
        pLItem->prv->nxt = pLItem->nxt;
        pLItem->nxt->prv = pLItem->prv;
        delete pLItem;
        count--;
    }
}
//! Gets a ListItem from a given index position in the AList.
/*!
In case that there is no ListItem stored at the given index of the List
this method will return a random value, or may lead to a Memory read exception.
This also applies if no item at all is stored in the list.

\param      index       [int]       The Index at which the ListItem gets removed.
\return     ListItem    [ListItem]  The ListItem at the position `index` in the list.
\sa Count()
*/
template <typename ListItem>
ListItem AList<ListItem>::GetAt(int index){
    PrivateListItem* pLItem = first;
    if (index <= count && index > -1){
        int i = 0;
        while(i < index){
            pLItem = pLItem->nxt;
            i++;
        }
    }

    return pLItem->crnt;
}
//! Gets the first ListItem which is stored in the list.
/*!
A random value will be returned if no items are stored in the list.

\return     ListItem    [ListItem]    The first ListItem in the list.
\sa Last(), Count()
*/
template <typename ListItem>
ListItem AList<ListItem>::First(){
    return first->crnt;
}
//! Gets the last ListItem which is stored in the list.
/*!
A random value will be returned if no items are stored in the list.
If there is only one Item stored in the list this method returns the same value as AList<ListItem>::First().

\return     ListItem    [ListItem]  The first ListItem in the list.
\sa First(), Count()
*/
template <typename ListItem>
ListItem AList<ListItem>::Last(){
    return last->crnt;
}
//! Gets the number of ListItems in the List.
/*!
The number is zero-based - A return value `0` means that there is one item stored in the list.
Please remember that a return value of `-1` means that there are no items stored in the list.

\return     int     [int]       Zero-based number of Items in the List.
*/
template <typename ListItem>
int AList<ListItem>::Count(){
    return count;
}

//! Clears the content of the List.
/*!

\return     void    [void]
*/
template <typename ListItem>
void AList<ListItem>::Clr(){
    PrivateListItem* pLItem = first;
    while(count > -1){
        PrivateListItem* tbdListItem = pLItem;
        pLItem = pLItem->nxt;
        delete tbdListItem;
        count--;
    }
}
```

My error:

```
PWM.cpp.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
PWM.cpp:4: undefined reference to `AList<Pwm>::AList()'
PWM.cpp:4: undefined reference to `AList<Pwm>::~AList()'
```

Again, AList is known to work and not mine, but I included it for reference. I've looked at every other question about this error, and none of them seem to apply to my issue. I understand this is a complicated question with lots of code, but thank you for looking at it and helping me out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On any normal C++ project, I would recommend putting the entirety of `AList` inside its header file; i.e. take the contents of `AList.cpp` and stick on the end of `AList.h` instead.

The reason is that many C++ compilers can't cope with the template definition being separated from the declaration like that. It may not apply to the compiler used by the Arduino IDE (I'm still quite new to it), but it's worth trying.

Another suggestion I would make is to put `#include "AList.h"` in your `PWM.h` header. Strictly speaking it shouldn't be necessary because of the inclusion order in `project.h`, but it's not always good to rely on that.

Comment: Yes, that makes the trick... I tried replacing `#include "AList.h"` with `#include "AList.cpp"` in `PWM.cpp`.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that actually. `#include` shouldn't be used for *.cpp files, as it can result in them getting compiled multiple times. It would be better to take all the contents of `AList.cpp` and paste it onto the end of `AList.h` (and then just delete `AList.cpp`).

Comment: Thanks for all the help! It compiles fine with AList.cpp pasted on the end of AList.h.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled around on this for hours. *The first answer works well, but leaves a bit to be desired, if you are wanting to compile your libraries as you build them.*

## My Setup (For your information)

- I'm not using Arduino's libraries folder, but instead referencing like so:

  `#include "../includes/MyClassName/src/MyClassName.h"`
- Sublime Text 3 beta with Stino plugin (HIGHLY RECOMMENDED - I enjoy it a lot!)
- Arduino IDE version: 1.5.6 beta

Ok, now on to the code. Here is MyClassName.h:

```
#ifndef MyClassName_h //If MyClassName_h "Not" DEFined
#define MyClassName_h //Then define MyClassName_h
class MyClassName{
  public:
    void get_computer_msg(boolean echo_cmd = false);
    String computer_msg;
    char first_char;
};
#endif //End if

#include "MyClassName.cpp" //Same as first answer recommends
```

Here is MyClassName.cpp

```
#ifndef MyClassName_cpp //the _cpp is just to delineate between the two files  
#define MyClassName_cpp
#include "MyClassName.h"
void MyClassName::get_computer_msg(boolean echo_cmd) { //Receive message from computer
  int index = 0;
  String msg = "";
  String echo_msg = "";
  if(Serial.available()) {
    while(Serial.available()) {
      char cChar = Serial.read();
      msg += cChar;
      echo_msg += cChar;
      index++;
    }
    if(echo_cmd) Serial.println("Computer sent " + echo_msg + "+CRLF");
    first_char = msg.charAt(0);
    computer_msg = msg;
  }
}
#endif
```

The benefit of doing it this way is that you can load up MyClassName.cpp, modify it, and then compile right then and there. If you have any errors, you'll know about it. Also, you won't have to update anything in MyClassName.h as MyClassName.cpp is included and the #ifndef's keep from double declarations.

The only thing I'm not sure about using this method is that compile time may still be hampered by the inclusion of MyClassName.cpp in the .h file. That is the main reason for having separate files in the first place. Perhaps an expert in C++ could comment on this?